# How do I change postfix sender address?

Tags: postfix

How do I make postfix send emails from `user@mydomain` instead of `root@hostname`? Even after installing and entering my domain when it asked, it's still being sent with the hostname and not the domain I provided. In my `main.cf` file

```
myorigin = /etc/mailname
```

and `/etc/mailname` contains:

```
gateblogs.com
```

which is my domain.

I have managed to fix my problem temporarily by changing my hostname to my domain name. However, how can I change who the email is from; currently mail is shown from `root` I want it to be something else.

Comment: How are you sending the email?  Using the `mail` command or what?

Comment: Yes. I'm using `echo "body" | mail -s blah email`

Comment: `mail -r fromaddress`.  See `man mail`.

Comment: How do I fix mail coming from `myhostname.mac.com`?

Comment: Did you read my previous comment?  Did you check the man page and read about the `-r` option?  Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: The `-r` option works great, but error messages seem to be sent differently.

Comment: Okay.  In that case, could you please [**edit your question**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/379175/edit) to make it clear exactly what the problem is that you're seeking to solve?  I'm not a Postfix expert but I don't see in your question what isn't addressed by just using `-r`.

Comment: After changing `/etc/mailname`, did you reload or restart postfix?

Answer (score 21):

Was having the same request and finally found and answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215388/changing-default-domain-in-mailutils)
(Would have flag this one as a duplicate)

User Rustyx at askubuntu answered this :

> To use a local domain other than the hostname in Mailutils:
>
> Create a file **`/etc/mailutils.conf`** with the following contents:
>
> ```
> address {
>   email-domain somedomain.com;
> };
> ```
>
> You can see what else can be configured in `mailutils.conf` with:
>
> ```
> $ mail --config-help
> ```

Please, take time to upvote [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215388/changing-default-domain-in-mailutils) if you feel it helps you.

Answer (score 13):

Postfix itself does not "set" the from address for an mail (as long has you haven't really tweaked the postfix configuration).
The from address header of an e-mail is set by the mail client which is asking postfix to deliver the mail (Postfix is a [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent)).

Hence you are looking at the wrong place - as far as I understand your question.

You mentioned that you are using the `mail` command to test your configuration.
This neat little command is - by default - using the systems user name under which the command gets executed. In your case this seems to be user `root`. Try executing `mail` as a different user and you'll see the from part changed.
And since the command `mail` does - by default - not append the domain part to the "from" header of the mail it hands over to postfix, postfix is appending the `myorigin` part automatically to `root`.

Though `mail` is not limiting you to not use some other "from" e-mail header. You can read about on the www or the [manual page of `mail`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mail). Also consider using [`sendmail`](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html).

Please note that postfix is a beast when it comes to configurability. You may accomplish almost everything you want postfix to do if you really understand its architecture and configuration files.
But since you are asking a quite 'newbee-ish' question you may not yet want to go down that road...

Comment: And for the record, `mail -r foo@bar.com` overrides the default behavior. Why do you suggest using `sendmail`? The relationship between `mail`, `sendmail` and `postfix` are pretty fuzzy. There is [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/244263/535132), but after reading all answers I feel almost more confused.

Answer (score 10):

The question is five years old, but I just had to set this up.

Issue:

I have a root@myserver that needs to be forwarded to my Office365. This requires my outgoing email on the server to always have FROM set to my 356 account.

In other words, when `root@myserver` sends an email, the FROM has to be re-written as `myaccount@myoffice356domain.com`.

Answer:

This re-write can be handled via a `/etc/postfix/generic` file.

In the postfix/main.cf add the following

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

Then create a `/etc/postfix/generic` file as below and add additional users if needed.

```
root@localdomain myaccount@myoffice356domain.com
@localdomain myaccount@myoffice356domain.com
root@myserver  myaccount@myoffice356domain.com
userA@myserver myaccount@myoffice356domain.com
```

Run Postmap and restart

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/generic
sudo systemctl restart postfix
```

All outgoing emails from both `root@myserver` and `userA@myserver` will automatically have the FROM SMTP field sent as `myaccount@myoffice356domain.com`.

Comment: Thanks. Wish I knew why one machine needed this and the other didn't... weird stuff. It works though!

Comment: If that doesn't work yet, and you get a warning like this in /var/log/mail.log:
`SendAsDenied; your.account@dom.ain not allowed to send as root@dom.ain;`
create a `/etc/postfix/sender_canonical` file with content like this
`root@dom.ain your.address@dom.ain`.
Then run `postmap /etc/postfix/sender_canonical` and restart the service again.

Answer (score 6):

You asked this twice, but I'll repeat my answer. In `main.cf`:

```
myorigin = $mydomain
```

Answer (score 4):

Using gue's and Bob Eager's answer, I figured out that the following setting in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` also does the job (on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine):

```
# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
# append_dot_mydomain = no  # --> this is the default setting
append_dot_mydomain = yes  # --> Setting it to yes appends the domain to the hostname
```

It also explains what gue said: appending the .domain is the Mail User Agent's job.
By setting it to `yes` we are overriding this.

So, my setup is :

```
[/etc/postfix/main.cf]
...
append_dot_mydomain = yes
...
myorigin = /etc/mailname
...

[/etc/mailname]
mydomain.example.com
```

Still, it doesn't feel like the right way; after all by setting it to `yes` we are violating the principle that "appending the .domain is the Mail User Agent's job"

Furthermore, I am not sure why I need to configure it this way to make it work. I have another server (configured by someone else; a Debian 8.11 machine), which does append the domain after the hostname correctly, even with  `/etc/mailname` being set to the domain, and with `append_dot_mydomain=no`. And on that server it works both for `mailx` and for mails sent by e.g. logcheck

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending mail with a PHP script: You can set the "from" portion of the header before you execute the `mail()` command.

e.g.

```php
<?php
$to      = 'target@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: noreply@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n" .   // this will show up as the from address
    'Reply-To: from.email@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .        // set this as the senders email so replys will go to them
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

This is how I have stepped around this problem in my particular situation.

Depending on your situation just setting these headers should be the solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider reading https://www.unix-experience.fr/postfix/rewrite_sender_dest/

```ini
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
recipient_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical
```